# LibreOffice in Windows 10 shows Red spelling correction line under all Hebrew words in all Hebrew passages

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, libreoffice

I have installed latest LibreOffice on Windows 10 and opened some documents that contain Hebrew passages.

There is a red correction line under all Hebrew words in all Hebrew passages.

Why is there a red line under all Hebrew words in all Hebrew passages?

In Microsoft Word I don't have such a problem: It can distinguish correct phrasing for both English and Hebrew, but in LibreOffice it just doesn't happen, in this case.

Comment: Download libre office of your language. See this link: https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?lang=pick

Comment: Please edit the question to show example text.  Is this modern or Biblical Hebrew, and Unicode or legacy font?  .docx or .odt?  For a specific answer to the problem, include a link to an example problematic document.  However, hopefully my answer below should allow you to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The language needs to be specified properly for CTL text, either the default language (described below) or specify it explicitly using *Tools -> Language -> For Paragraph*.

Go to *Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Languages*.  Under *Default Languages for Documents / Complex text layout* specify `Hebrew`.

I also went to *LibreOffice Writer -> Basic Fonts (CTL)* and specified `Ezra SIL` as the default font, but this should not affect spellchecking.

[image: hebrew text not underlined]

This is the text shown in the example:

```
WLC - בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃
In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. - NKJV
Thhe kwick brownn foxx jumpped owver tthe laezi dawg.
```